# Websettings.SetAppCacheEnabled deprecated, what to use instead?

Tags: android, android-websettings

During an attempt to bring an older android application into the modern world, I have come across the deprecated statement of:

```
websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(false)
```

What is the modern Androidx alternate?

Comment: did u get solution ?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use this

`webView.settings.cacheMode=WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE`

Refer : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings

Comment: what if I had `websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)`, what should I set now?

Comment: @user924 You can always opt-in for cache data using WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY or .LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK.

Answer (score 29):

Alternatively, this helped me out:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Comment: what if I had `websettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)`, what should I set now?

Comment: @user924 this line of code is not depreciated, that's why we have the new line of code that gives the same result.

Comment: @user924 use webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT); or webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);   LOAD_DEFAULT does not use expired cache but LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK does